# Error on compilation 'my_bool' - Droplet on DigitalOcean Debian 9.12

Tags: azerothcore

I've been following the installation guide from https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/digital-ocean-video-tutorial

During the compiling process, an `my_bool` error has occured and stopped the process. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlK74.jpg

From the github issues, I could only find that this could be related to incorrect MySQL, and the solution is to use MariaBD but I already use MariaDB.

Comment: what version of AzerothCore are you using? this problem should be solved in latest version

Comment: commit db4b7e00fcd2a794d95a1339dba5be01bc491b25
Author: AzerothCoreBot <azerothcorebot@gmail.com> Is this what you were looking for? I simply used the ```git clone https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk.git --branch master --single-branch azerothcore```

Comment: what version of mysql are you using?

Comment: mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.44-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Comment: can you try using the latest version of mariadb or mysql? that version it's quite old and it's supported only until October 2020...

Comment: So, I've moved from Debian 9 to Debian 10 and all issues have been solved.

Comment: probably it was about the version of mysql/mariadb that was too old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was using an outdated version of mysql/mariadb.

It's better to either use mysql 5.7 or 8.0 or latest mariadb version.

Comment: Just to reconfirm: mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.22-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2                            cmake --version
cmake version 3.13.4                  clang --version
clang version 7.0.1-8 (tags/RELEASE_701/final)